# Combine input and output streams

Tags: c++, redirect, input, output

I want to combine both input and output stream to the output stream.
I mean, if this is my code:

```
int num;
string str;
cout << "string: ";
cin >> str;
cout << "num: ";
cin >> num;
cout << "num is " << num << " str is " << str;
```

And I redirect the input stream to a txt file contains:

> hey 1

My output stream will contain:

```
string: hey
num: 1
num is 1 str i hey
```

insted of:

```
string: num: num is 1 str is hey
```

**I don't want to cout each variable in cin after I get my input. I want it to be automatically.**

Comment: Output some newlines?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the output doesn't contain the input values either, not just new lines.

Comment: __"I want it to be automatically."__ So you're lost.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ in c# I inherited the input stream class and override the ReadLine method and added a print before value returned. Can't I do something like that in c++?

Answer (score 0):

### Overload std::istream::operator >> for a wrapper class and do what you like:

```
// Example program
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class AutoCinToCoutReader {
    public: 
        inline void write(const std::string& in) { std::cout << in << std::endl; }
};

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, AutoCinToCoutReader& dt)  
{  
    std::string in;
    is >> in;
    dt.write(in);

    return is;  
}  

void read(const std::string& what, AutoCinToCoutReader& rd) {

    std::cout << what << ": ";
    std::cin  >> rd;
}

int main()
{
    AutoCinToCoutReader rd;

    std::vector<std::string> fields = { "Test1", "Test2" };

    for(const std::string& field : fields) {
        read(field, rd);
    }
}
```

### Update:

The smallest thing I could offer is:

```
// Example program
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>

std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, std::ostream& os) {
    std::string in;
    is >> in;
    os << in << std::endl;
    return is;
}

void read(const std::string& what) {

    std::cout << what << ": ";
    std::cin  >> std::cout;
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> fields = { "Test1", "Test2" };

    for(const std::string& field : fields) {
        read(field);
    }
}
```

You can not immediately write into cout from cin. In any case, you need to work around it. See the updated operator, directly outputting to cout after storing in cin.

Comment: I don't want a wrapper class, I am writing tests for a function that should be written without any changes in use of cin and cout.

Comment: See update... And by the way, I'm just calling std::cin, std::cout... so I don't change their use.. Just where I use them...